# Interfacing between Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to interface between Python and C++. I am trying to initially do it in simplest case, e.g. to find mean. My main is in python

1)Function getInput (python)

2)Function CalculateMean(C++)

3)Function DisplayMean(python)

My python file (main.py) looks like this:

```
function getInput(x,y)
//Here I want to add the function CalculateMean written in cpp file
function displayMean(m)
```

"CalcMean.h"

```
int CalculateMean(int x,int y)
```

"CalcMean.cpp"

```
mean = CalculateMean(x,y)    
{
mean = (x+y)/2;
return mean;
}
```

I have tried using SWIG, but I am a begineer and unable to solve it. Any basic help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need a simple swig interface file that imports your CalcMean.h and produces a module, something like this into a mymodule.i file:

```
%module mymodule
%{
    #include "CalcMean.h"
%}

%include "CalcMean.h"
```

then you can launch swig with something like

./swig -python -o mymodule.o mymodule.i

this will produce a .o file to be compiled as an .so/.dll file, as well as the required .py file to import the module.